# What's the difference between --no-igd and --igd disabled in the monerod options?

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands

I'd like to explicitly forbid UPnP port mapping.

Does setting `--igd disabled` have the same effect as setting `--no-igd`? From https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/ :

- `--no-igd`: *Disable UPnP port mapping on the router ("Internet Gateway Device"). Add this option to improve security if you are not behind a NAT (you can bind directly to public IP or you run through Tor).*
- `--igd`: *Set UPnP port mapping on the router ("Internet Gateway Device"). One of: disabled | enabled | delayed (=delayed by default). Relevant if you are behind NAT and want to accept incoming P2P network connections. The delayed value means it will wait for incoming connections in hope UPnP may not be necessary. After a while w/o incoming connections found it will attempt to map ports with UPnP. If you know you need UPnP change it to enabled to fast track the process.*

Comment: Unfortunately MoneroDocs.org is no longer available, but you can see this same content at https://getmonero.dev/docs/interacting/monerod-reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does setting `--igd disabled` have the same effect as setting `--no-igd`?

Yes. There is functionally no difference between `--no-igd` and `--igd disabled`.

> I'd like to explicitly forbid UPnP port mapping.

Use either `--no-igd` or `--igd disabled` then.